# How to create a SOAP webservice in Spring 6.x

Tags: spring

I am looking for something like this for the version 6.x:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/reference/remoting.html#remoting-web-services-jaxws-export-servlet

Honestly I am not able to find it. Is it not possible to produce a SOAP webservice in Spring 6.x?.

Note that this is not Spring Boot. For Spring Boot I found this: https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service

It is valid to me if somebody can illustrate it with one example.

Comment: This is the response to my question: https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/reference/html/#_i_introduction